# "Key" on a BucketAggregate is missing when the response is serialized

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am working on upgrading a service from ES 5.0 to 6.8. I have a bucket aggregate that in v5 serializes to this:

```
      "items": [
        {
          "key": "random+topic",
          "docCount": 27919,
          "aggregations": {
            "ParentReference": {
              "docCount": 24992,
              "aggregations": {
                "Popularity": {
                  "value": 25223
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "unknown problem+latency",
          "docCount": 24566,
          "aggregations": {
            "ParentReference": {
              "docCount": 23419,
              "aggregations": {
                "Popularity": {
                  "value": 23931
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
```

With the v6 of Elasticsearch.Net and Nest, when serialized, I end up with:

```
      "items": [
        {
          "ParentReference": {
            "Popularity": {
              "value": 25223
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "ParentReference": {
            "Popularity": {
              "value": 23931
            }
          }
        },
```

I had previously encountered the issue where the "aggregations" property is no longer returned (though I would love a pointer to the breaking changes announcement on that), and have updated my code accordingly. I can't do much without the Key and docCount, however. I figure there must be something related to the Json parsing changes.

I have already tried the steps in:
[Custom Serialization | Elasticsearch.Net and NEST: the .NET clients [6.x] | Elastic](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/6.x/custom-serialization.html)

I have tried with the default serializer, as well as a custom one using the JsonNetSerializer.Default to no effect.

Can anyone provide a suggestion on what I should be doing?

note that this is how I am getting my BucketAggregate:

```
        var childAgg = response.Aggregations[ss.Type] as SingleBucketAggregate;
        var nestedAgg = childAgg.Aggregations[ss.Path] as SingleBucketAggregate;
        var countAgg = nestedAgg.Aggregations[ssTermsName] as BucketAggregate;
        return new ProviderResult<BucketAggregate>
        {
            Result = countAgg,
        };
```

Thank!
~john

additional:

ElasticClient elasticClient_BuiltInSerializer = new ElasticClient();
var source = elasticClient_BuiltInSerializer.SourceSerializer.SerializeToString(o);
var response = elasticClient_BuiltInSerializer.RequestResponseSerializer.SerializeToString(o);

```
            ConnectionSettings connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://fake")), JsonNetSerializer.Default);
            ElasticClient elasticClient_JsonNetSerializer = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

            var source2 = elasticClient_JsonNetSerializer.SourceSerializer.SerializeToString(o);
            var response2 = elasticClient_JsonNetSerializer.RequestResponseSerializer.SerializeToString(o);
```

Comment: Hey John, re-serializing high level responses isn't supported functionality, they only support deserialization of JSON into an instance of a response.

Comment: Please take a look at this issue, which discusses some approaches you may want to take: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/3093#issuecomment-366158401